# Seeing confusing notifications about my wired connection when there is no Ethernet cable connected

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ethernet

Let me preface by saying I'm a linux noob. I've just wet my feet by installing Lubuntu 20.04 LTS on an old Dell Inspiron n411z that I had lying around. The machine works great but I'm troubleshooting minor annoyances.

Issue: I'm seeing confusing activity surrounding my Ethernet port even though I have nothing plugged in.

I kept seeing a notification "Wired Ethernet Connection disconnected" that popped up every few minutes. I never connected anything to the port to begin with so this was confusing. I was able to find a setting on nm-tray in the system tray to disable notifications so I dealt with this issue there.

However, I would still occasionally see my connection indicator in the system tray keep spinning even when I have a perfectly working Wi-Fi connection.

I decided to investigate and read up more. I found commands like systemctl and journalctl to gather more information. Here's what I know so far:

```
kp@voltron:$ journalctl -g enp4s0 -f
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-06-18 20:28:13 PDT. --
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065117.1037] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065117.1205] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065117.1207] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> done
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:05:17 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5390] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5407] device (enp4s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5484] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (d818283c-4769-35fd-80ae-e60b60978a85)
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5487] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5499] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.*.
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5534] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:06:25 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065185.5543] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 24 23:06:31 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:06:42 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:06:45 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065211.0982] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065211.1125] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065211.1127] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> done
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:06:51 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4533] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4537] device (enp4s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4608] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (d818283c-4769-35fd-80ae-e60b60978a85)
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4610] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4616] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4644] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065273.4698] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:07:53 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.*.
Jun 24 23:07:57 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:07:59 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:08:00 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:08:06 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:08:06 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:07 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:08:09 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:08:09 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:14 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:15 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:08:18 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:08:24 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:27 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:08:33 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <warn>  [1593065318.8418] dhcp4 (enp4s0): request timed out
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8419] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8421] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <warn>  [1593065318.8462] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'                                                                                     
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8469] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8724] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8725] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
Jun 24 23:08:38 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065318.8769] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:08:39 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:41 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:08:44 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:08:55 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:08:55 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:09:01 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:09:09 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:09:12 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:09:13 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:09:26 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:09:27 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:09:29 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:09:36 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:09:45 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:09:45 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:09:46 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:09:57 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:09:59 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:10:03 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:10:11 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:10:13 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:10:20 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:10:23 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:10:24 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:10:31 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:10:36 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:10:37 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:10:42 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:10:48 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:10:49 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:10:52 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron kernel: atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.6898] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.6903] device (enp4s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.6974] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (d818283c-4769-35fd-80ae-e60b60978a85)
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.6976] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.6982] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.7012] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065460.7017] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:11:00 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.*.
Jun 24 23:11:02 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:11:03 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:11:03 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:11:10 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:11:21 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:11:22 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:11:23 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:11:40 voltron dhclient[3060]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xac0ae07d)
Jun 24 23:11:42 voltron dhclient[2536]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x19ff7a4d)
Jun 24 23:11:42 voltron dhclient[2851]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x40845655)
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <warn>  [1593065505.8405] dhcp4 (enp4s0): request timed out
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8406] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8408] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <warn>  [1593065505.8456] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'                                                                                     
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8462] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655 on enp4s0.
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::46ef:88c2:a128:b655.
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron avahi-daemon[785]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8725] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8725] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
Jun 24 23:11:45 voltron NetworkManager[3013]: <info>  [1593065505.8784] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Why are there so many processes interacting with my ethernet port (enp4s0)? How can I get these services to stop doing this when nothing is connected to the port?

I hope the above logs are useful enough for someone to give me pointers. Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent sometime digging around and I think I found the solution to my problem.

Reading the comment from the user wilkinsmr on this thread helped me a lot:
https://gist.github.com/mohamadaliakbari/1cb9400984094541581fff07143e1c9d

I had systemd-networkd.service AND NetworkManager running and from what I could understand I really only needed one of these services to manage my networks. I understood at a high level that NetworkManager is preferred for desktops and systemd-networkd is for servers.

Next I realized something was wrong with my dhcp on NetworkManager. I understand that NetworkManager uses its own internal dhcp server and I confirmed this by checking:

```
NetworkManager --print-config
```

Sure enough I saw:

```
dhcp=internal
```

I followed wilkinsmr's recommendation and modified /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and configured dhclient as the default

```
#/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

I'm not sure why leaving it as 'internal' was causing issues for me. However once I changed this, I went ahead and disabled 'systemd-networkd.service' and rebooted and since then my NetworkManager has been working perfectly.

I was able to confirm that it is indeed using dhclient as the dhcp.

I use a PiHole in my home network to block ads and have also configured it as my default dhcp server. I wonder if the internal dhcp of NetworkManager has any issues working with the PiHole DHCP. For the time being though, my issue is resolved.